# Image on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I want to display 6 diferents images, each one on a aJPanel. I try adding the images to a JLabel but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
public DocumentPanel2() {

    initComponents();

    List<String> imagenes = new ArrayList<String>();
    imagenes.add("/imagenes/fondoPanel.jpg");
    imagenes.add("/imagenes/button.jpg");
    imagenes.add("/imagenes/primera.JPG");
    imagenes.add("/imagenes/segunda.JPG");
    imagenes.add("/imagenes/tercera.JPG");
    imagenes.add("/imagenes/cuarta.JPG");

    List<JPanel> paneles = new ArrayList<JPanel>();
    paneles.add(jPanel1);
    paneles.add(jPanel2);
    paneles.add(jPanel3);
    paneles.add(jPanel4);
    paneles.add(jPanel5);
    paneles.add(jPanel6);
    for(int i = 0; i < imagenes.size(); i++)
    {
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(imagenes.get(i))).getImage());
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setIcon(image);
        paneles.get(i).add(label);
    }
  }
}
```

This code is in the GUI on the public class DocumentPanel2 extends javax.swing.JPanel. I expect a panel with 6 panels inside, each one displaying an image but I just get the panel with 6 panels displaying nothing.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: _What_ doesn't work? What do you expect and what do you get instead? Please be more specific.

Comment: Amen. "it doesn't work" tells us nothing.

Comment: And where do you add these JLabel holding JPanels to any component that is on the GUI? Why use JPanels at all? Why not just add the JLabels to a container that's on the GUI?

Comment: Why the double constructor call? new ImageIcon(URL) is sufficient.

Comment: Sorry, this code is in the GUI on the public class DocumentPanel2 extends javax.swing.JPanel. I expect a panel with 6 panels inside, each one displaying an image but I just get the panel with 6 panels displaying nothing

Comment: @user1163956: again, where do you add anything to a container that is displayed in the GUI? Your comment above tells us little as we still don't see code where you're adding any of these little JPanels to the current class. And again, why not simply add the JLabels?

Answer (score 2):

You're not adding the JPanels that hold the JLabels to any container that is visualized on the GUI. Better still, don't even use intermediate JPanels, but just add the JLabels with the images themselves to a container that is held by the GUI. You need to be sure that the container (usually a JPanel) uses a layout manager that will layout and display the JLabels well, such as a GridLayout(3, 0). If the components are added after the GUI has been displayed, don't forget to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container JPanel after adding the JLabels.